# What should be the redirect URI for yammer when using a windows phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, windows-phone-8, yammer

I am using the following URL for **OAuth2.0**

https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&response_type=token

and passing this to the Post().

Result: **My App does not run and waits for the resources. i think probably it is not getting the HTTP response.**

Please validate and let me know what i have done wrong in here?

```
private void Post(string address)
    {
        System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(address);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request); 
    }

// STEP4 STEP4 STEP4
    private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        string results;
        using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
             results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //TextBlockResults.Text = results; //-- on another thread!
            SkyDriveContent test = new SkyDriveContent();
            test.Name = results;
            str_results = results;

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ContentList.Add(test));
        }
        myResponse.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the async and await syntax? It makes threading problems much more apparent.

Comment: I'm no yammer expert. But the issue with Mobile Oauth and redirect URIs is pretty common. Have you read up on it? See @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121757/oauth-callback-procedure-for-mobile-devices